# Can I pre-register or register a domain with a new domain suffix from ICANN directly?

Tags: domains, godaddy, top-level-domains

I want to buy a domain with the suffixes: `.zone` and `.moe`

I have found some sites that say you can pre-register them, which are listed below:

`https://www.instra.com/en/domain-names/brand/zone-domain-registration/zone
 https://www.gandi.net/domain/gtld/eoi?word=zone.zone
 http://www.101domain.com/domain-availability-search.htm`

For now, it's seems I cannot pre-register a domain with those suffixes.

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Does anyone know if above websites are trustable?
2. If normal domain sellers will sell these suffixes, when can I get this information? I think it would be too late after I know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to pre-register or register a domain directly from ICANN, unless you are an [Accredited Domain Registrar](http://www.internic.net/regist.html).

[Generic top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) (gTLD) can be pre-registerd at domain registrars only after they are [approved](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/customer-service/faqs/faqs-en) to do so by ICANN.

Without commenting on the trust-worthiness of the URL's you listed in any way, ICANN [warns](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/customer-service/faqs/faqs-en):

**`1.9 Can I pre-register a second-level domain name?`** 
`Be wary of anyone who claims to be able to reserve your place in line for a second-level registration for one of these new gTLDs. Not only can no one predict which TLDs will be available, but the new TLD operator may choose not to sell second-level registrations.`